# Integral when there is modulus

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I know its a easy integral but my  problem with the  modulus part.
$$\int_0^{10} |x-5| dx$$

Without modulus I can solve it very easily.

Comment: Hint:  Break it into a sum of *two* integrals (each over part of the original range).  If you do it right you can remove the modulus.

Comment: I just need to know that how to remove the modulus

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT:** $$\int_0^{10} |x-5| dx$$
$$=\int_0^{5} (5-x) dx + \int_5^{10} (x-5) dx$$

Answer (score 1):

Evaluate $x-5$ and see where it has negative solutions and positive solutions. This way you can divide your current integral in $2$ other integrals without the modulus part.

Answer (score 1):

Try graphing $|x-5|$. In particular, $|x-5|=x-5$ whenever $x-5$ is positive, or when $x\ge 5$.

Then $|x-5|=-(x-5)$ whenever $x-5$ is negative, or when $x\le 5$.